# Multiple SELECT statements with different WHERE condition in one query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't know what's the proper syntax but hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT Count(BookCategory) AS TotalBookAC
FROM Passenger
WHERE BookCategory='AC';
SELECT Count(BookCategory) AS TotalBookGen
FROM Passenger
WHERE BookCategory='General';
...
```

What `keyword` is needed to **join** two or more sql statement in one?

### Edit

*Passenger*'s table:

```
TicketID - PK
TrainNumber - FK
BookDate - As Date
PassengerName - varchar
Age - num
Sex - varchar
Address - varchar
ReservationStatus - 'waiting' OR 'confirmed'
BookCategory - 'CP' OR 'General'
```

*TrainList*'s table:

```
TrainNumber - PK
TrainName - varchar
Source - varchar (place)
Destination - varchar (place)
FareAC - num (currency)
FareGeneral - num (currency)
DayAvailable - varchar (weekdays)
```

Now I'm struggling how could I construct an SQL statement that will query a distinct *TrainList.TrainNumber* and fields for the `Count` of *AC* and *General* in *Passenger.BookCategory*.

And here's an example output I want to achieve

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| TrainNumber | TotalSeatsGen | TotalSeatsAC | TotalBookGen | TotalBookAC  |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1      |       10      |      12      |       11     |      13      |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+

       ^                                 . . .
    DISTINCT  <--       specific records for this TrainNumber only       -->
```

Comment: You probably should read up on basics of SQL. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. The table you have shown had extra columns which has no where mentioned in your question. So first you need to specify schema and then pose the question and explain what you did to find answer.

Comment: Are train number and seat category also in table Passenger or in another table?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's a foreign key. I guess I'm missing a lot of details I needed to jot down.

Comment: Okay, so how do you get from the numbers of bookings to the number of seats (TotalSeatsGen and TotalSeatsAC)? Is it the records where ReservationStatus = 'confirmed'?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, that's the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all records from table Passenger and count occurences. So you must scan the whole table and count conditionally. In standard SQL you would use CASE WHEN; in MS Access you'd use IIF. The counting is done with SUM; you add a 1 per match, so you are actually counting.

```
SELECT 
  TrainNumber,
  SUM( IIF(BookCategory = 'General' and ReservationStatus = 'confirmed', 1, 0) ) AS TotalSeatGen,
  SUM( IIF(BookCategory = 'AC' and ReservationStatus = 'confirmed', 1, 0) ) AS TotalSeatAC,
  SUM( IIF(BookCategory = 'General', 1, 0) ) AS TotalBookGen,
  SUM( IIF(BookCategory = 'AC', 1, 0) ) AS TotalBookAC
FROM Passenger
GROUP BY TrainNumber 
ORDER BY TrainNumber;
```

Comment: I've edited my answer according to the new information that you get the seats by looking at the reservation status. Nothing complicated, only `AND ReservationStatus = 'confirmed'` in the conditions.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, Thank you for your answer! This is just the complete set of commands I am looking for. I'm about to make a multiple queries equivalent from your `SUM ( IIF...` statements, but you just have save my time by doing this :D

Answer (score 0):

Its simple answer,

> declare @Passenger table (id int, BookCategory varchar(50))
>
> insert into @Passenger
>   values (1,'AC'),(2,'AC'),(3,'General'),(4,'AC'),(5,'General'),(6,'AC'),(7,'AC'),
>   (8,'General'),(9,'AC')
>
> select * from @Passenger
>
> SELECT BookCategory, --Count(BookCategory) totalcount
>
> case when BookCategory='AC' then Count(BookCategory) end AS TotalBookAC,
>
> case when BookCategory='General' then Count(BookCategory) end AS TotalBookGen
>
> FROM @Passenger
>
> WHERE
>
> BookCategory in ( 'AC', 'General')
>     group by BookCategory
>
> select * from 
>   (
>
> SELECT BookCategory, Count(BookCategory) totalcount
>
> --case when BookCategory='AC' then Count(BookCategory) end AS TotalBookAC,
>
> --case when BookCategory='General' then Count(BookCategory) end AS TotalBookGen
>
> FROM @Passenger
>
> WHERE
>
> BookCategory in ( 'AC', 'General')
>     group by BookCategory
>   )
>   a

Comment: Yes...The `CASE WHEN` is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Uhmm...I'm having syntax errors, is the syntax you present is standard? Can't do it in access :3

Comment: The above SQL query (or more likely stored procedure) does not work in Access! It might be T-SQL. The OP asked for Ms Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BookCategory, Count(*)
FROM Passenger
GROUP BY BookCategory;
```

Then do the rest in the presentation layer of the application

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate query for each count you need.

Let's say they will be called qryTotalSeatsGen, qryTotalSeatsAC, qryTotalBookGen, qryTotalBookAC.

Each query will have two fields: `TrainNumber` and `Total`

Now create a final query with all the above mentioned queries. Join them all on `TrainNumber` and include each one's total in the field.

```
SELECT qryTotalSeatsGen.Total AS TotalSeatsGen,
 qryTotalSeatsAC.Total AS TotalSeatsAC,
 qryTotalBookGen.Total AS TotalBookGen,
 qryTotalBookAC.Total AS TotalBookAC
FROM (qryTotalSeatsGen INNER JOIN qryTotalSeatsAC ON qryTotalSeatsGen.TrainNumer = qryTotalSeatsAC.TrainNumer)
 INNERJOIN ....
```

Use the Ms Access query builder (as the above query I wrote out by hand just to give you the idea, it may not be exact).

Comment: Couldn't be this achieved by one query and one SQL statement only?

Comment: Yes. See Thorsten Kettner's answer. Just performance wise you will be better off without the IIF function.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #FinalResult
(
Tno INT,
TotSeatGen INT,
TotSeatAC INT,
TotBookGen INT,
TotBookAC INT
)

INSERT INTO #FinalResult(Tno) VALUES (1)


UPDATE #FinalResult SET TotBookAC = (SELECT Count(BookCategory) AS TotalBookAC FROM Passenger WHERE BookCategory='AC') WHERE Tno =1
UPDATE #FinalResult SET TotBookGen = (SELECT Count(BookCategory) AS TotalBookGen FROM Passenger WHERE BookCategory='General') WHERE Tno =1
............
............
............

SELECT * FROM #FinalResult
```

Comment: But I want is just a query. If I do this, I am in need to always update this table.